# BaseClass functionality not working in react native

Tags: react-native

Am totally stuck with something. Working on deep link and its redirection. When clicking on a deep link it's getting redirected to my app. I have added the code to handle in my `HomePage.js`.

***Scenario 1:*** 
If app is removed from background in phone then the deep link redirection works great

**Scenario 2:**
If app is kept at HomePage.js and left in background of device. then on deep link click opens the app no redirection happens.

***Scenario 3:*** 
If app is kept at HomePage.js which have `AppState.addListener()` and left at background and then on click of deep link HomePage state change listener is hit but there is no url.

**Expected behaviour**
App should detect its being redirected when its on any page with the url.